# Even after change in value in beforeEach hook, the original value is used for dynamic tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

**My setup:**
I am running some dynamic tests on cypress i.e. that I get a list of some names in environment variables. The number of tests depend on the number of names in this list.

**My aim:**
What I want to do is that manipulate this array which contains the list in such a way that if it contains the word 'ALL' passed through the environment variable then I want to change the array and add all the names that I get using an API call. This gives me the option of getting all names instead of writing them one by one manually.

**My problem:**
Although beforeEach() runs before the test the value contained in my array remains the same that I got through my environment variables. I assume that the code in *describe()* but outside *it()* and *beforeeach()* runs first... however even after *beforeEach()* runs and updates my array, when the tests start they still use the older value coming in from the environment variable.

I want to conditionally update my array depending on what is passed in the environment variable "ALL" or some names.

My code:

```
describe('[' + Cypress.env('TEAM') + ' - ' + Cypress.env('CLUSTER') + '] - ', () => {

    let dataPoolsArray: string[] = Cypress.env('DATAPOOLS').split(',') // this is being read directly from env variable

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.defaultLogin()

        if ( Cypress.env('DATAPOOLS') === 'ALL') { // Depending on my env variable I want to change the value of the array here
            dataPoolsArray.length = 0
            let i = 0
            cy.Integration_DataPool_findAll().then((getDataPoolsResponse) => {
                getDataPoolsResponse.body
                .forEach((dataPool: any) => {
                    dataPoolsArray.push(dataPool.name) 
                    cy.log('dataPoolsArray:  ' + dataPoolsArray[i])
                    i ++
                })
            })

        }

    })



    dataPoolsArray.forEach((poolName) => { // However when I run my test it just takes "ALL" as the only value in the array

        it('Data Model for pool: ' + poolName, () => {
            cy.log('Checking if datamodel loaded for the pool: ' + poolName)
            cy.sendPqlQueryToAnalysisConnectedToPool(poolName)
        })

    })


})
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** you're trying to generate `it` test cases dynamically by synchronously looping through an array which is populated asynchronously in `beforeEach` hook --- even if the code inside that hook *was* synchronous (which it's not), the hook itself is run *after* you generate the `it` tests below.

**Solution:** AFAIK, there's no other way other than to populate the `dataPoolsArray` array synchronously, and outside any hook -- since Mocha (and Cypress) requires the suites (`describe`) and test cases (`it`) to be registered synchronously.

With that being said, you can possibly generate the whole test file, either before running cypress, or by pre-processing the test file itself, [somehow](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/preprocessors-api.html#Examples).